# Can DB constraits ignore existing records and apply for only new data?

Tags: database, constraints

I want to learn the answer for different DB engines but in our case;
we have some records that are not unique for a column and now we want to make that column unique which forces us to remove duplicate values. 
We use Oracle 10g. Is this reasonable? Or is this something like goto statement :) ? Should we really delete? What if we had millions of records?

Comment: Just curious as to why you'd want to enforce uniqueness for new records only?  I assume there's a good reason why you'd want uniqueness in a column which previously did not enforce uniqueness?

Comment: Just becasue lack of design specs. This should exist at the beginning but we realized now.

Comment: so far it seems DB engines don't like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using NOVALIDATE ENABLE constraint state, but deleting is much more preferred way.

Comment: Yes, DDL is something like
ALTER TABLE [your_table] MODIFY CONSTRAINT [your_constraint] ENABLE NOVALIDATE

Comment: Or ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ... ENABLE NOVALIDATE if you are adding new constraint.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as posted: *No, it can't be done on any RDBMS that I'm aware of*.

However, like most things you can work around it, by doing the following.

**Create a composite key, with a new column and the existing column**

You can make it unique without deleting anything by adding a new column, call it PartialKey.

For existing rows you set PartialKey to a unique value (starting at Zero).

Create a unique constraint on the existing column and PartialKey (you can do this because each of these rows will now be unique).

For new rows, only use a default value of Zero for PartialKey (because zero has already been used), this will force the existing column to have unqiue values in the table.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

This is weak - if you delete a row with partial key 0. Now another row can be added with a value that is already in the existing column, because the 0 in partial key will guarentee uniqueness.

You would need to ensure that either

1. You never delete the row with
   partial key 0
2. You always have a dummy row with
   partial key 0, and you never delete
   it (or you immediately reinsert it automatically)

**Edit: Bite the bullet and clean the data**

If as you said you've just realised that the column should be unique, then you should (if possible) clean up the data. The above approach is a hack, and you'll find yourself writing more hacks when accessing the table (you may find you've two sets of logic for dealing with queries against that table, one for where the column IS unique, and one where it's NOT. I'd clean this now or it'll come back and bite you in the arse a thousand times over.

Comment: we cleaned the data, but such a case can be faced in the future, and good to know such a hack, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in SQL Server.

> When you create a check constraint,
>   you can set an option to apply it
>   either to new data only or to existing
>   data as well. The option of applying
>   the constraint to new data only is
>   useful when you know that the existing
>   data already meets the new check
>   constraint, or when a business rule
>   requires the constraint to be enforced
>   only from this point forward.

for example

```
ALTER TABLE myTable 
WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT myConstraint CHECK ( column > 100 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your records straight before adding the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can put a constraint in a enable novalidate state. When a constraint is in the enable novalidate state, all subsequent statements are checked for conformity to the constraint. However, any existing data in the table is not checked. A table with enable novalidated constraints can contain invalid data, but it is not possible to add new invalid data to it. Enabling constraints in the novalidated state is most useful in data warehouse configurations that are uploading valid OLTP data.